# Sliding Navigation Drawer back in

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

So I have recently implemented the Navigation Drawer into my application and I have a few weird things going on.  one of the most annoying is that once I slide the Nav Drawer out and you release your finger, the only way to get it back in is to click on an option or somewhere on the screen, you cant slide it back in with your finger.  Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so how did you resolve?